# soundcloud in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, cloud, soundcloud

i wish to use soundcloud  in a jquery mobile page. I copy pasted the following:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F63422331&show_artwork=true"></iframe>
```

from http://soundcloud.com/amar-dj/

It works well in chrome browser but when i upload the jquery page on mobile, the track doesnt play.
Also I wish to customize the soundcloud widget to include the track, play button and the artist and track name that's it. No like or share button! For this i wrote the following:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F63422331&amp;&show_artwork=false&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false&sharing=false&buying=false;color=ff7700"></iframe>
```

All but the like button disappears. How do i hide the like button?

Comment: Hey z22. I have tried to use your embed code and I do not see like button. Could you specify which browser exactly you are using?

Comment: Could you also let us know what does this line mean "when i upload the jquery page on mobile, the track doesnt play"?

Comment: i am using chrome : Version 21.0.1180.57

Comment: please ignore the line "when i upload the jquery page on mobile, the track doesnt play" as this was due to some other reason. it is solved now

Comment: Hey z22, do you still have some trouble? `&liking=false` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: yes the problem still persists. Everything but like disappears :(

Comment: If you could put your code somewhere like http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net I'd be glad to look at it

Comment: sure check out http://jsfiddle.net/2UPbt/

Comment: both the like ,and now the buy link too, are seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this problem, you should now be able to hide purchase link as well by supplying `buying=false` parameter (the problem is fixed and deployed).

As for the like button, please notice that in your example you have not placed an ampersand (`&`) between `liking=false` and `color=ff7700`. If you add it, you won't see `like` button.